# Retrieving commits for a specific time frame using Terminal

Tags: git, curl, github, terminal, commit

This may seems like a fantastically simple question, but I'm kind of stuck now. I'm trying to use Terminal on OSX to retrieve a list of commits since a certain date, specifically since 1 year ago. I've tried the code below:

```
curl -i -u my_username https://api.github.com/repos/:user/:repo/commits?since=2017-08-16
```

This returns a list of commits, but the list ends in January of this year. In looking at the page I know there are commits much older than this, so something's not working quite right. I have also tried this formatting for the parameter:

```
curl -i -u Starplatinum87 https://api.github.com/repos/d3/d3/commits '{"since":"2017-08-1600:00:000"}'
```

But this returns a `curl: (3) Port number ended with '"'` error.

Not sure if it's how I'm stating the parameter, the formatting of the date or something else.

Any resources that detail the proper syntax for GitHub operations through Terminal/curl would be very helpful too. I know this is a very basic question.

Help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Visiting https://api.github.com seems to show a list of URLs and their parameters.

Comment: Great thanks! I started in totally the wrong place in the documentation. Should have just gone to the beginning...

Comment: I didn't know where to look. I actually found this by accident.

Comment: That's how I find things like this way too often :-)